# Understanding equation solution

Tags: calculus

I'm reading a book that shows this equation:

$\frac{dY}{dt} = \beta - \alpha Y$

which describes $Y$'s change in concentration rate depending on some factors.

Later it says:

"The solution to equation [above] with $\beta = 0$ is an exponential decay of Y concentration:"

$Y(t) = Y_{st} e^{-\alpha{t}}$

(For completeness, $Y_{st}$ stands for "Y steady", i.e. when Y reached a constant concentration).

Can anyone explain how we go from the first equation to the second one? it makes sense intuitively, but I don't know the steps involved in solving it.

Comment: The equation $\frac{\mathrm{d}Y}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\alpha Y$ is an example of a separable ODE. There's a set method for solving such equations, and you can find an explanation with examples [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_211_Calculus_II/Chapter_8%3A_Introduction_to_Differential_Equations/8.3%3A_Separable_Differential_Equations), say. If the book doesn't explain this, I imagine it's not important that you know *how* it's solved, but if you're curious, you can follow the link or look up further resources.

Comment: Thank you! will give it a look. Yeah it's not important to follow along with the book, but I want to know.

Comment: It's also an example of a first order linear ODE, for which there's another method that will solve the equation. If you don't like the separation of variables used for separable ODEs for whatever reason, you can try looking at integrating factors for first order linear ODEs instead.

Comment: @User If it is a decay $(\alpha >0)$, then $Y_{st}$ is the **initial** concentration. It decreases over time. And $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} Y(t)=0$

Comment: @User Has it occurred to you that if you want to know then maybe it is important to follow along with the book?

Comment: @JohnDouma you probably misunderstood: the point is that the book does *not* explain it (and that understanding it is not really relevant to follow along with the book, I'm just curious).

Comment: @callculus42 yes, for the exponential equation specifically, it is initial concentration. The "st" comes from context (the previous state essentially).